# 'Cannot Access a closed file' error on some files

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm getting `Cannot Access a closed file` on some files when I try to upload them. I'm creating a small web app, when a user creates an account on the website, they are required to upload a file. Once they have uploaded the file, I should see it in MongoDB. The issue is some files are uploaded successfully while others create errors. This is the exact error msg from the log:

```
[ERROR]: Cannot access a closed file.
    ExceptionType: System.ObjectDisposedException
    StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
    at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    at System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent.TempFile.GetBytes(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Byte[] buffer, Int32 bufferOffset)
    at System.Web.HttpInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
    at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count)
```

this is the `httpRunTime`:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="41943049" requestLengthDiskThreshold="153609" />
```

All files are below 5MB, files are either: pdf, jpeg, or png.

This is how I am reading the file:

```
public string addDocument(HttpPostedFile file, string typeOfDocument, int UserID, string documentID = "", int uploadedBy = 0)
{
    Stream stream;
    BinaryReader bReader;
    byte[] bytes;
    stream = file.InputStream;
    bReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    bytes = bReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
}
```

The rest of the code in `addInternshipDocument` is about adding the file to Mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it had to do with the `httpRunTime`. My computer I had:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="41943049" requestLengthDiskThreshold="153609" />
```

but on our testing server we had different numbers. I changed our testing server's `httpRuntime` to match the one on my computer.